# Projection of a random i.i.d matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-matrices

Let $A$ be a random matrix with i.i.d entries. Under what conditions does  $CA$ has i.i.d entries? Particular interest is (a) when $C$ is fixed deterministic matrix and   (b) When $C$ is i.i.d random. In the latter case, does any condition on $C$ imply that $CA$ has i.i.d entries? Any reference will be appreciated. For this particular problem, $C$ is a projection matrix.

Comment: Is $C$ independent of $A$?

Comment: @Brian yes, C is independent of A

Comment: If you can place no further restrictions on $A$ (besides its entries being iid), I have a hard time imagining _any_ scenario where $CA$ has iid entries, except trivially when $C$ is a permutation matrix.  The "identical distribution" part is easy, but the "independent" part is ... hard for me.

Comment: @antkam There are variants of a permutation matrix such as if $A$ is $3\times 3$ and $C=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @Henry - you are right.  $C$ can obviously (and still "trivially" IMHO) be any subset (of rows) of a permutation matrix, and can obviously be rescaled by any scalar.  Now that I think about it, a slightly less trivial case is $C=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\ 0& 5& 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and similar.  But even if the latter case is not entirely trivial, it's still very "basic" - in the sense it is entirely combinatorial and has nothing to do with iid property.

Comment: @antkam, thank you for your responses. Would there be an interesting case where CA is iid for some assumption on C and A (e.g restricting A to a class of random matrices, Gaussian?) or is that too much to expect?

Comment: @user795301 - That's the point I'm making -- I can't think of any non-trivial examples that actually utilize properties of the random entries in $A$.  All the examples so far guarantee independence by making sure no two entries of $CA$ share any entry of $A$.

Comment: @antkam, I see your point, the operation for non-trivial C clearly creates coupling